# How to make fog/ Fog is not showing?

Tags: materials, node-editor

So I watched a tutorial on how to make fog and it showed just to add a volume scatter node, but when I do this nothing shows up, it's just blank. I'm basically trying to recreate the PS2 intro fog and need to be able to see it from a far distance looking downwards.

There are screenshots from my project:[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you in eevee or cycles?

Comment: evevee @Yohello1

Comment: Try increasing your density and see if it does anything?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that if you are using an older version than 2.8 to check volumetrics in render properties tab and adjust the end clipping if you scene is large.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't give me the option to check it

Comment: Then you must be using newer blender version .It is enabled by default.Make sure your volumetrics settings are same as mine.If still the problem persist share your .blend file

Comment: How do I share the file?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ -use this to share you file.Also try tweaking the strength if your lights

Comment: I tried to upload it? Im not sure if it worked. Yea I checked the cube and it just straight up disappears/ becomes see through. @nxdhin2005

Comment: Your file isn't uploaded

Comment: I just add in the url and hit upload right?

Comment: Don't forget to drag and drop your file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110264/discussion-between-nxdhin2005-and-murth).

Answer (score 0):

Your scene seems to be very large. There are some things you should check / try:

1. in the rendering "Volumetrics" tab: usually the visibility starts at 0.1m and ends at 100m - probably you got to adjust those values
2. increase density of your Volume Scatter node
3. you need light to make your fog visible, probably increase the light strength if you already have lights in the scene

Comment: Could i add a glow node to the fog?

Comment: When I increase the density nothing happens, my end is already at 50000 for volumetrics, and I tried the light but nothing :/

Comment: His scene is fairly big but the object to which volume scatter node is applied is small

Comment: afaik you cannot add a glow node to your fog. Currently I can think of two things: The object itself could be displayed as bounds in the viewport, or it is just disabled.

Comment: maybe just create a cube with basic dimensions and add your material to it, if everything is as described you should see the fog. Maybe the issue occurs when scaling up (at a certain point)...

Comment: It will still work if the object is displayed as bounds in the viewport